# Subscribe to a topic in rqt plugin

Tags: ros, topic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to subscribe to a very simple topic (/chatter) from within an rqt plugin but I cannot get it to work. After I boiled down the code it looks essentially like this:

```
void MyPlugin::initPlugin(qt_gui_cpp::PluginContext& context)
{
  mainWidget = new MainWindow();

  if (context.serialNumber() > 1)
  {
    mainWidget->setWindowTitle(mainWidget->windowTitle() + " (" + QString::number(context.serialNumber()) + ")");    
  }
  context.addWidget(mainWidget);

  // this is where want to subscribe
  sub = n.subscribe("chatter", 1000, &MyPlugin::chatterCallback, this);
}
  

// this is my callback function 
void MyPlugin::chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}
```

Of course sub and n are declared in the header and the code compiles.

Only problem is: Nothing happens..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81501/subscribe-to-a-topic-in-rqt-plugin/) by [alu](https://answers.ros.org/users/6941/alu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I found the problem. It is important to get the NodeHandle from the plugin and not to create one yourself.

---

Originally posted by [alu](https://answers.ros.org/users/6941/alu/) with karma: 26 on 2013-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bapclenet](https://answers.ros.org/users/11526/bapclenet/) on 2014-07-29**:
How do you get the NodeHandle from the plugin?
sub_ = getNodeHandle().subscribe("/topic",10,callback); results on a:
Failed to load nodelet ...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you checked e.g. via `rqt_graph` or `rosnode info` that your nodes are actually connected on that topic?

If your NodeHandle would be initialized with "~", therefore being private, you would subscribe to `/node_name/chatter`, unless you add a `/` to the subscribe call.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-09-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alu](https://answers.ros.org/users/6941/alu/) on 2013-09-23**:
Yes, it seems that my node appears when I do not "hide Debug" and it also subscribed to the topic. I do not initialize my node handle at all, so its going to be standard constructed.
It seems like the problem is in the callback, which does not get called